# SUSE YaST routes not in kernel route -n

Tags: routing, openvpn, opensuse

I'm using openSuSE as a router. `eth0` is the WAN NIC, `eth1` is the LAN NIC. I also have a `tun10` device, which I'm using with an OpenVPN client connection.

I want yast routes to specify what traffic has to go out over the OpenVPN tunnel. All other traffic should continue to go out over `eth0` (the default route). That's why I'm using `route-nopull`, since the OpenVPN server pushes a default route for `0.0.0.0/32`.

However, I don't see the routes defined in yast show up in `route -n`.

How can I make them work?

The IP addressed below are made up. (Except one for [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com))

**OpenVPN client.conf**
some excerpts

```
client
route-nopull
dev tun10
proto udp
```

**YaST network settings -> routing**

> default gateway: 101.102.103.104
> device: eth0
>
> routes: (just one example)
>
> - destination: 141.101.120.15 ([whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com))
> - gateway: 10.20.30.40
> - genmask: 255.255.255.255
> - device: tun10

**`route -n` output**
the marked lines only show up when I start the VPN tunnel *without* `route-nopull`

```
Destination Gateway         Genmask         Flags Iface
0.0.0.0     10.20.30.40     128.0.0.0       UG    tun10 //without route-nopull
0.0.0.0     101.102.103.104 0.0.0.0         UG    eth0
10.0.0.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     eth1
128.0.0.0   10.20.30.40     128.0.0.0       UG    tun10 //without route-nopull
10.20.30.40 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    tun10 //without route-nopull
10.20.30.41 10.20.30.40     255.255.255.255 UHG   tun10 //without route-nopull
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, YaST will not create those rules for you. If you really want to use YaST, I can not help - but if you only want to make your routes work, try this:

Add a *route* option to your OpenVPN client configuration (see [the OpenVPN man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) at *--route* for details). That way the routes will be added after a successfull connection is made with OpenVPN.

For example:

`route 141.101.120.15 255.255.255.255 10.20.30.40`